# Can't install eth-brownie on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, brownie

I am trying to install eth-brownie using the documentation, on Ubuntu 20.04.2.
I've been going in circles for hours, trying to do everything the messages are telling me.

1. pipx install eth-brownie

   gives:
   Not installing to existing directory '/home/me/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie'. Pass '--force' to force installation
2. fine, I tried with --force, and then got the following:

   Installing to existing directory '/home/me/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie'
   The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
   available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
   package using the following command.

   apt-get install python3-venv
3. I know I already have python3, because when I type python3 I get:
   Python 3.8.5, blabla

   But ok, let's try doing what it says. Tried, asked to use sudo. Added 'sudo' in the beginning, and got:
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   python3-venv : Depends: python3.8-venv (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I searched for similar questions and have been going at it for hours. I tried the 'update' command, 'the 'upgrade' command, the 'dpkg' thing, and every suggestion I could find.
I just want to have eth-brownie. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some errors on Ubuntu too. But it worked installing Brownie on a virtual environment.

> 1. Install Virtual Env:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

> 2. Create a Virtual Env:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 .
```

> 3. Activate the Virtual Env:

```
$ source bin/activate
```

> 4. Then you can run the brownie pipx install command:

```
$ pipx install eth-brownie
```

It should install, and you can deactivate the virtualenv just typing "deactivate" after.
And you will not need to activate virtual env anymore to run Brownie.

PS: Don't create the virtualenv on the same folder of your brownie project. If you start a Brownie Project with the "brownie init" command, it will give an error requesting the folder to be empty.

Comment: Thank you Vitor. Unfortunately, it didn't work.After activating the virtual environment, I get:

(me) me@me-Satellite-P55W-C:~$ pipx install eth-brownie --force
Installing to existing directory '/home/me/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie'
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv
.....

Comment: Your answer was actually very helpful and worked once I downgraded to Python3.8.2 :)